# Get Branch Revision Number

Tags: bash, git

I have branch A. Head Revision is 1. Then, I create branch B from branch A with head revision 1.

Afterwards, I am using branch B, until the head revision changed as below:

```
1
2
3
4
10 <- HEAD
```

Is there any Git Command I could run in branch B to get the revision number when 
the branch B first branch out? In this case, I want the command to return 1 as 1 is the head revision of branch A when branch B is created from branch A.

Thank you,

Hatjhie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
      5 - 6 - 7 (HEAD -> B)              
     /     
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 8 (A)
    ^
    |
   (fork point)
```

You can run

```
git merge-base --fork-point A
```

on B to see where A was forked from B.

> git [`merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) finds best common ancestor(s) between two commits ...

Comment: The fork-point option computes a somewhat different answer, using reflogs. In this case that somewhat-different answer *may* be what the OP really wants, but it's not clear. Note that in many simple cases, both the regular merge-base and the fork-point merge-base operation will select the same commit hash ID anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use this command:

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n'' %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all
```

you will get the things you want.

source:

https://gist.github.com/eamanu/1c30435ff6e2f9ebb1ef8ef359c9d34c